# Programmatically select files using C#

Tags: c#, windows, sdk, winapi

When the user selects file(s) or/ and folder(s) , I want to know the names of the selected file(s) or/and folder(s) programmatically.

I think that if I send the message lvm_selected to the explorer window, it might return me the selected item.

But as this is just a thought, it would be nice if anyone can help me out it in letting me know the proper way .

I would prefer this in C#, but C++ shall also be fine.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Do you want to monitor what the user does on their machine and which folders they go to, or are you just looking to bring up an Open File dialog within your app and have the user pick something?

Comment: I'm usually against responding to questions with "Why are you doing that.. you should do something else" but this time I have to agree with @Anna Lear a little bit simply because I'm not sure what you're asking for can be done reliably and also because there may be a better way to achieve your end goal.

Comment: @Anna , @Miky I am developing a part of a software , which should return me the path of the selected files or folders. I am not looking into Open File Dialog . Lets say the user has selected two files, and I want to know the path and file name of the selected file .

Comment: And by "selected" you mean "selected in Windows Explorer"? What if the user has multiple Explorer windows open?

Comment: @Mattias Good question. But I think even if the user has multiple files selected in different explorers, in my case I would select the explorer which has the focus. I think Windows does the same also .

Comment: And what if none of the Windows Explorers has focus? (E.g., what if your program has focus instead?)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/AutomateShellWindow.aspx
Note the method is broken by UAC. Write a BHO if your customer have UAC on.